# fit container to the content of contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make draggable div that has text inside which can be edited.

But for fixed height and width, container div don't fit to the content of `editableContent` div.

Setting `.container` height to `auto`, working fine, but I want it to be resizable so, it won't work.

Also I tried using JavaScript to set container height by counting every line break of editableContent div, but when I don't press `enter` it doesn't count as `<br>`

I'd really appreciate any guidance.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content" contentEditable></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use <textarea></textarea> for the resizable content or container

Answer (score 1):

you can use textarea property.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<textarea class="container">
  <textarea class="content"></textarea>
</textarea>
```